# Don't understand why Quickblox video chat sample login times out

Tags: quickblox

I'm currently trying to try Quickblox before integrating it on our products, but I still can't run the video chat samples, both on android nor ios.
I've created a test backend application, configured the credentials as explained in the documentation but when I try to run the samples I got the same behaviour : the session creation seems to be OK but when QBChat::loginWithUser is called, nothing happend. chatDidLogin or chatDidNotLogin are never called and the session expired several seconds after.

Another sample (location) seems to work with the same credentials : sending a position with comment cause the message to be updated in the back end.

Any idea ?

Comment: please post Xcode logs

Comment: Thanks for your support but I finally found that a port was not open on ou firewall (shame on me). So now the iOS/iOS communication works fine. The Android/Android and iOS/Android too. But I still have problems with the Javascript SDK : the call event is catched by the calle but the "accept" button of the sample does not do anything. I'm going to check again my config (now I run on a non-firewalled network for my test). I currently perform an evaluation of conferencing SDK for a product we developp and I think we should need "1 to N" conferencing. Can Quickblox be used to achieved that ?